# Using font as icon library

Tags: css, fonts, zk

I am trying to use [entypo](http://www.entypo.com) as the source for the icons in my webapp. This webapp I am developing using ZK as the UI technology.

The problem is, when I try to use an icon from that font using:

```
<span sclass="entypoWhite">&#128100;</span>
```

I get the following error: `'' (0xd83d) is not a valid XML character`

Am I doing anything wrong?

PS. I am using ZK version 5

Comment: `&#128100;` looks strange to me. Sure this is the right one? Maybe you need `&#123;&#100;`.

Comment: check http://www.entypo.com/characters/ the 4th icon on the second row

Comment: http://www.codetable.net/decimal/128100

Comment: You're saying I should use the Hex equivalent? Cause it didnt work either

Comment: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3mj8rtq/2-special-chars for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its a bug from ZK itself.

They have there own DOM verifier and from `&#100000` it goes wrong.
That's why also the `&#9666;` do work.

Following me the error is here :

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.zkoss.common/zcommon/6.5.1/org/zkoss/idom/Verifier.java#Verifier.isXMLCharacter%28char%29

At the method at line 227.
I'll post a bug report for it : http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-2261

Comment: Wow, that sucks :( Moreso when I'm stuck with version 5 so any corrections wont be applied.

Comment: No, that's not true, Its a kind of util class. So v5 will make same use of it as v7.

Comment: But they must update the ZK 5 dependencies for the change to be reflected don't they?

Comment: Normally they shall do that, with the experiance I have (and otherwise class overriding with the class from zk7)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing network problems involving the parent proxy, and the body of the HTTP response contains a human-readable description of the problem in HTML format. Your service client is trying to parse this text as XML and therefore your error.

Remove the hexa decimal value of ' from the encoded string.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because this one: `&#9666;` does work